# How should I distribute my app with my own OAuth2 client ID, without letting anyone find it out?

Tags: api, security, oauth2, golang

I've written an app using **golang** which uses OAuth2(Authorization code flow with PKCE) to interact with the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api).
If I build the app using my own *client ID* then my *client ID* can easily be found out through the *authorization request URL* which my app passes to the system browser during *user consent*. This won't be a good practice since basically anyone could impersonate my client using my *client ID*.

### My question

How am I supposed to distribute my app with my own *client ID*? If it's not possible with this flow, do any other alternatives exist?

Comment: Should not the users be using their own client IDs?

Comment: That's a way but I wanted the app to have a presence of its own.

Comment: Then create dedicated credentials for the application.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod You're not understanding my issue. I already have a dedicated pair client ID for this app. My main issue is that anyone can easily find that client id, since the app passes it as a variable through the authorization request URL. Once a person finds it, it's trivial for him/her to impersonate the app. I was wondering if this could be mitigated.

Comment: I don’t believe it can be.

Comment: Well, to execute the OAuth flow, an outsider only needs a client ID. (Note: here, it's not the credentials of the end user that are being compromised, it's just that I'm not okay with other API clients claiming that they're mine, by giving Google my app's client ID

Answer (score 2):

Don't store your clientID on the client. Your app should store it's clientId and secret on the server. When a user signs into your app, they should begin an OAuth request through your server. Your server sends a token request to Google's Oauth endpoint, Google will return your server a authorization url that you redirect the client to. The client logs in to google using the authorization url and google redirects to your endpoint supplying the User's token. Your app can store the token on the client and use it for authorized access to the Google APIs on behalf of the user.

Possibly the best route to properly implementing this functionality is to use a 3rd party OAuth provider like Auth0 that handles the plumbing for you. They have walk through tutorials to show you how to integrate with various endpoints like Facebook, Google, and Twitter. https://auth0.com/docs/

Comment: The main issue is that the client ID is plainly shown in the user consent page's URL. Even if I follow all this, in the end, the end user will have to provide user consent through his/her browser, and there my client ID will be out in the open. I think using PKCE would be a simpler approach giving the same results as this, but I'm still open to other methods

Comment: No your server starts the authorization request and the URL the google api generates has a unique key that is not your client ID.

Comment: Also even if they have your clientID they need your secretkey to spoof you. the client id is like a username, you can't do anything with it unless you have the password.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try to implement this server flow. Concerning the `clientID`, only `clientID` is sufficient to impersonate me, since people can avoid `client secret` through AuthCode with PKCE flow. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/08/22/okta-authjs-pkce/?utm_campaign=text_website_all_multiple_dev_dev_oauth-pkce_null&utm_source=oauthio&utm_medium=cpc

Comment: I want to correct myself. I've found out right now that for exchanging authorization code with token, `client_secret` is a must. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#exchange-authorization-code